# Understanding While Loops and Counter - How does it work?

Tags: javascript

**Understanding While Loop**

I am trying to understand what exactly happens when I use the 'while loop' to execute a code multiple times.

I was solving a problem on JSHero.net and I found it confusing so I tried explaining the solution to myself in order to get a clear understanding.

Please study the question, the answer and the simple explanation and let me know if I have understood it correctly. I could have done better explaining the counter as using it inside the condition itself confused me a lot.

Thanking all the good people in advance for helping me !!

Stay Safe !!

### Question

Write a function spaces that takes a natural number n and returns a string of n spaces.
Example: spaces(1) should return ' '.

### Answer

```js
function spaces(num) {
  let mySpaces = '';

  while (num-- > 0)
    mySpaces += ' ';

  return mySpaces;
};
```

### Explanation

- declare a function spaces
- it has 1 parameter 'num'
- declare a variable mySpaces
- initialize it with an empty string
- we use a while loop as we need to repeat an action multiple times
- in this case we need to add blank spaces to a string
- our '''empty spaces string''' will be stored in the variable mySpaces
- blank spaces will be equal to the 'num' parameter, which is fed when the function 'spaces' is called
- while loops have: a condition and a code (loop body)
- our condition is to ensure that the code should execute as long as the num is greater than 0
- our condition is (num-- > 0)
- our code is: mySpaces += ''
- so if our function is called with the following parameter then how would this while loop work
- spaces (3)
- first it will check if 3 > 0; which it is and it will execute the code
- mySpaces = mySpaces + ' '; the result in variable mySpace will now be ' ' (1 space)
- then since we have used the num as a counter (num--), the loop will reduce 1 from 3 = 2
- it will check if 2 > 0; which it is and it will execute the code
- mySpaces = mySpaces + ' '; the result in variable mySpace will now be '  ' (2 spaces)
- then since we have used the num as a counter (num--), the loop will reduce 1 from 2 = 1
- it will check if 1 > 0; which it is and it will execute the code
- mySpaces = mySpaces + ' '; the result in variable mySpace will now be '   ' (3 spaces)
- then since we have used the num as a counter (num--), the loop will reduce 1 from 1 = 0
- it will check if 0 > 0; which it is not and it will only execute the code after the while loop
- we return the mySpaces variable which will give us the final result

Comment: Actually it goes like "first it will check if 3 > 0; (which it is) and then it reduces `num` by one, and then it will execute the code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While construction in javascript and most popular programming language consists of these parts:

1. `while` keyword
2. condition inside parentheses (`num-- > 0`)
3. body (`mySpaces += ' ';`)

It it used to repeatedly execute statements inside the body as long as condition is true.

For example this is how would you print `Hello world` repeatedly 5 times (please note, for this example `for` loop would have been more appropriate):

```
i = 5;
while (i > 0) {                  // as long as i is above zero
    console.log("Hello world");  // print 'Hello world'
    i--;                         // decrease value of i by one
}
```

In this particular example execution of while loop could be described as this:

- check if condition is true

  - if not - skip body and continue with next statement after body
  - if yes - execute every statement inside body once and repeat this step

It is possible based on the condition that body gets executed zero, one, or multiple times.

In your code you start with some value of `num`, when you enter while loop, condition is checked, it is determined, whether body should or should not be executed and then `num` is decreased by one (because of the `--` operator). This process repeats as long as `num` is above zero.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification in the order:

...
<> spaces (3)

<> a variable `mySpaces` will be declared and initialized with an empty string literal.

<> first it will check if 3 > 0; which it is and it start the loop. The value of `num` has already decreased by 1 in the memory, so now `num` = 2.

<> mySpaces = mySpaces + ' '; the result in variable mySpace will now be ' ' (1 space)

<> it will check if 2 > 0; which it is and it will execute the code. The value of `num` has again decreased by 1 in the memory, so now `num` = 1.

<> mySpaces = mySpaces + '  '; the result in variable mySpace will now be '  ' (2 spaces)

<> it will check if 1 > 0; which it is and it will execute the code. The value of `num` has again decreased by 1 in the memory, so now `num` = 0.

<> mySpaces = mySpaces + '   '; the result in variable mySpace will now be '   ' (3 spaces)

<> it will check if 0 > 0; which is false and it will not execute the code inside the while loop anymore. The value of `num` has again decreased by 1 in the memory, so now `num` = -1.

<> The last value of `mySpaces` which is '   ' (3 spaces) is returned from the function.

P.S. I've tried to write the answer in a way closest to how you've explained it. Hope this clears everything! Next time if you find the flow of code confusing always remember to put print statements at different places. Putting a `console.log("Checkpoint 1")` or printing the value of the variables in action greatly helps one to understand the changes as they happen. A more advanced way is to put breakpoints in code and debug. OnlineGDB's IDE makes a table of values for the variables and displays them at each stop.